# node.js crashes when serving video file

Tags: node.js, libuv

I'm serving static video files (.ogv and .mov) with node.js and video.js plugin.  However, node.js keeps crashing with below error message:

```
node: ../deps/uv/src/unix/stream.c:1319: uv_read_stop: Assertion `!uv__io_active(&stream->io_watcher, 4) || !(&stream->write_completed_queue == (&stream->write_completed_queue)->prev) || !(&stream->write_queue == (&stream->write_queue)->prev) || stream->shutdown_req != ((void *)0) || stream->connect_req != ((void *)0)' failed.
```

This is node.js code:

```
app.configure (function () {
    app.set ('views', path.join (__dirname, 'templates'));
    app.set ('view engine', 'jade');

    app.use (express.favicon (path.join (__dirname, '/img/favicon.ico')));

    app.use ('/video', express.static (path.join (__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use (express.static (path.join (__dirname, 'public'))); 

    //bodyParser, methodOverride, cookieParser and session calls here

    app.use (app.router);
});
```

my node.js version is "**v0.10.4**"

Directory structure:

- /myApp

  - /myApp/public

    - /myApp/public/video

A pretty straight forward static file serving.  Tried placing express.static after app.router, and above favicon, no such luck.

Appreciate any advice render.

Comment: It looks like it could be a Node bug. Try using the latest version of Node (0.10.8) to see if that solves your problem. If not, try and remove parts of your application so you are left with a minimum version of it that either still crashes, or fixes the problem (in which case you could narrow down which part of the application is responsible for triggering the problem).

Comment: Upgraded to 0.10.8.  Error persists.

Comment: Create a minimal example and submit [an issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues), I think it's a bug.

Comment: Tested with 1MB .ogv file, no error.  My original .ogv is 14MB, .mov is 58MB.  Probably due to file length issue in Express.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem (`.mp4`, 57MB, Node 0.10.8 on Mac OS X), but it might depend on your exact application setup (other middleware that you're using, for instance).

Comment: Open issue tracking #5569

Comment: Fix in next 0.10 release.

Comment: I have to say that assert in node is horrible. Someone should split it up into separate asserts.

Answer (score 1):

So, for the sake of completeness: This is a [known bug](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5569) in `libuv` which [has been solved](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/commit/b38c9c1) since `0.10.9`. There has been a similar issue which [is resolved](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/commit/8e4b248) since `0.10.11`.